# How to use kubeconfig file as credential in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am using jenkins on a separate instance and eks for running k8s cluster. Currently I'm using my local machine to deploy any changes to cluster using kubeconfig and aws-iam-authenticator with the help of kubectl. Now I want to deploy any changes to cluster using Jenkins, I have installed Kubernetes, Kubernetes CLI plugin. Below is my kubeconfig file content,

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: My-Cluster-Api-Server-Endpoint
  name: Cluster-ARN
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: My-Cluster-Api-Server-Endpoint
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: Cluster-ARN
    user: Cluster-ARN
  name: Cluster-ARN
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: aws
  name: aws
current-context: Cluster-ARN
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: Cluster-ARN
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - token
      - -i
      - cluster-name
      command: aws-iam-authenticator
      env: null
- name: aws
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - token
      - -i
      - cluster-name
      - -r
      - arn:EKS-Service-Role-ARN
      command: aws-iam-authenticator
      env: null
```

How can I use my kubeconfig file to get access to my K8s cluster.
I have added my kubeconfig file as credentials but when I am generating pipeline script code for kubernetes cli plugin the credential dropdown is not showing the added kubeconfig credential.
[image]

Comment: How about use command in your Jenkins script? `sh(aws eks --region eu-west-2 update-kubeconfig --name YOUR_CLUSTER)`